How to choose a flyback diode with limited information
I would like to protect the MOSFETs in my BMS (JBD-SP04S034-L4S-200A-H) from any back EMF resulting from the shutdown of a large (1/2 HP, 39 A, 12 V DC inductive motor). I unfortunately do not know the stall current.
At the moment I turn on/off the motor with a large mechanical battery switch located at the motor. From reading, it looks like I might not need a free wheeling diode if I am willing to accept sparking in the switch. Can someone please confirm that is how that would work.
In either case, I would like to protect the circuit. What specific diode should I consider?

MOSFETS in the BMS? I'd need to see a schematic or diagram of how your motor is hooked up and where the MOSFET is in relation to the motor in order to understand your requirements.

What are your currents and voltages? Do you have a nameplate on the motor?

Assuming the motor only turns in one direction, a rectifier like this one connected directly across the motor is probably okay, and is one of the least expensive 50-100A rectifiers. You can also get older packages of similar parts (such as hermetic stud mount) at a significant price premium.
It will not require a heat sink, if the motor is just switched occasionally.
It is capable (with a heat sink) of 60A continuous and will withstand a 450A pulse of substantial duration (8.3ms half sine wave).

The typical peak current it will experience when switched off with the motor running is 39A, and worst-case will be the motor LRA, and it can accommodate such an impulse at more than 10x the run current.

I’ll have to make sure my motor can only run in one direction because I have no idea. Assuming it does, is there anything stopping me from soldering 6AWG wire directly to the pins of this mosfet? I could put heat shrink for isolation right up to the base of the mosfet body. If I’m able to do that, it sure will make adding ring terminals and final installation much easier.

When I look at the spec sheet, I see it shows a “base cathode”, and anode and cathode. I only need to use the anode and cathode pins when wiring, right?

@JeffO'Neill There are only two connections. You can use the two pins. 'Base' is connected to exposed metal on the back of the plastic package. If you bolt it down to a conductive material, that material will also be connected to the cathode pin.
